# Best way to authenticate user

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth

I'm searching best way to sign up, log in in my app.
There will be three ways to log in: facebook, g+ and my website.
When user log in by facebook, app sends fb auth token to my website which creates an account in my server db with informations from fb acc. When app starts the same thing is going.. its checking if user is logged into fb account if he is, then sends the token... bla bla

But I dont know how to log in user who is using website account. How to keep him logged in? Should I keep his password somewhere?

Maybe should I use OAuth on my website? But whether it is necessary?

How do you handle this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Read docs of AccountManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the app starts an account is created for the user at your website, right? Take that username & password and save it in SharedPreferences. The next time the user runs the app check if username and passworod exists in sharedPreferences.

Also, when the user edits his/her profile, update the user info in the sharedPrefrences. I don't think you need to implement OAuth in your website for the app. The user wouldn't like to log in everytime he/she runs the app.

And if you get null for username/password from the sharedPreferences then use facebook login again and update the info again (This scenario is very rare).

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [persistent data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)! You are going to use shared preferences to save a hidden file on the devices android system. Then if the user already has that hidden file with the data then you pull there login information or if they don't you ask them to log in.